# What is Joe McCool's problem with Gerry Quinn?

Tags: character, derry-girls

In *Derry Girls* Joe McCool, Mary and Sarah's father, and Erin and Orla's maternal grandfather, has lived with the Quinns since his wife died. Joe shows nothing but contempt for Gerry, constantly criticising him and encouraging Mary to leave him.

> JOE MCCOOL: Why can't you just leave my Mary alone?

Has any in-episode dialogue or commentary from the creators ever explained what Joe McCool's problem is with Gerry Quinn?

Comment: I thought it was just a joke about how Joe doesn't think Gerry is good enough for Mary, despite them having children and a happy solid relationship. Possibly started as a general grumble, though in S1E6 Joe puts his hand on Gerry's shoulder as they watch the news, either for support or giving comfort, so it may now be more of a habit and a tease than real animosity.